# How to update multiple Swing components (JLabel) at once - prevent one-by-one updating/repainting

Tags: java, swing

I have simple display class. Each digits is represented by one `JLabel` with set icon from 0 to 9.

```
public class Display extends JPanel{

    private static final int DIGIT_COUNT = 3;
    private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[DIGIT_COUNT];
    private Icon[] numbers = ResourceManager.getInstance().createIconSet(ImageSetResource.DISPLAY_NUMBERS,13);


    public Display(){
        GridLayout layout = new GridLayout(1,DIGIT_COUNT);
        setLayout(layout);
        for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
            labels[i] = new JLabel();
            labels[i].setIcon(numbers[0]);
            add(labels[i]);
        }

        setNumber(0);
    }

    public void setNumber(int number){
        int max = 10 ^ DIGIT_COUNT -1;
        if (number < 0 && number > max)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number needs to be in range <0, " + max + ">");

        int[] digits = getDigitArray(number);

        for (int i = 0; i < digits.length; i++) {
            labels[i].setIcon(numbers[digits[i]]);
        }

    }

    private int[] getDigitArray(int number){
        int[] digits = new int[DIGIT_COUNT];

        int leftover = number;
        for (int i = 0; i < DIGIT_COUNT; i++){
            int result = leftover % 10;
            leftover = (leftover - result)/10;
            digits[DIGIT_COUNT -1 -i] = result;

            if (leftover == 0)
                break;
        }
        assert leftover == 0;

        return digits;
    }

}
```

This display is also used to update the time every second. The value displayed is set at method `setNumber()`. The problem is that when update is, for example, from 9 to 10 or from 79 to 80, it is visible that first `JLabel` responsible for 10^1 value is update and 10^0  value `JLabel` only after that.

Is there a way how to achieve that all `JLabels` are always updated at the same time from the user  point of view?

EDIT:

1.Simple Swing timer code:

```
 ActionListener taskPerformer = new ActionListener() {
          public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
             display.setNumber(secondsPassed);
          }
      };
 new Timer(1000, taskPerformer).start();
```

2.@Marco13 thanks for pointing out that silly beginner-like circumflex error.

3.@user1803551 The problem is that within `JLabel.setIcon()` the `JLabel.repaint()` is called.
Meaning that if I set the icons one by one also the `JLabels` can be updated one by one. I am not sure about the `JLabel.setText()` though.

I tried to put together SSCCE but there all labels were painted at once and the problems was not visible Maybe too simplified example. I cannot say as I am do not possess knowledge regarding the `Swing` painting internals.

What I am looking for is for a way to somehow disable repainting on the component (which is called from the `setIcon()` method) and repaint the specific groups components at once.

Comment: Post your [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org/) that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: An aside: I'm pretty sure that `int max = 10 ^ DIGIT_COUNT -1;` is **NOT** doing what you think it does. It does **NOT** compute "10 to the power of DIGIT_COUNT" - the `^` is a bitwise XOR, and the result here will most likely be garbage. (It might even be related to the problem, but... who knows.). You should probably use `int max = (int)Math.pow(10, DIGIT_COUNT)-1;` instead.

Comment: `I tried to put together SSCCE but there all labels were painted at once...` - Exactly and that is why you create a SSCCE, to simplify the problem. Now you have to look at your real code to see what the difference is. We can't help you because we have no idea what your real code looks like. `and repaint the specific groups components at once` - this is the default behaviour of Swing. The `RepaintManger` receives painting requests and groups them together to do one repaint. If they don't paint together then you have some time delay between setting the icons of each label.

Comment: This is actually the case when all the actual code is posted here as it is not so long. It is contained within `setNumber()` method and I included the timer code as well. My problem is that I cannot even say if this is normal behavior or there is something bad in my code. I just cannot see anything wrong there. Subsequent paint requests all done on event dispatch thread.

Comment: If it works in the SSCCE, you just proved it works as expected. If it doesn't work in your real program then you are doing something different/wrong. Why would the length of your code change in your real application? The Timer code to update the labels should be the same.

Comment: `...within JLabel.setIcon() the JLabel.repaint() is called... I am not sure about the JLabel.setText() though.` They both call repaint. Maybe try to replace your icons with strings and see if you still get the same problem. If my code runs for you then you can start to transform it into your code until you get where it stops working.

Answer (score 0):

I rewrote parts of your code to make it shorter and more efficient and also simulated a timer running in the background. I had to replace your icons with regular strings.

```
public class Display extends JPanel{

    private static final int DIGIT_COUNT = 6;
    private static final int MAX = (int) Math.pow(10, DIGIT_COUNT) - 1;
    private JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[DIGIT_COUNT];
    private String[] numbers = new String[] {"0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"};

    public Display(){

        for (int i = 0; i < DIGIT_COUNT; i++)
            add(labels[i] = new JLabel(numbers[0]));
    }

    public void setNumber(int number){

        if (number < 0 && number > MAX)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number needs to be in range <0, " + MAX + ">");

        for (int i = 0; i < DIGIT_COUNT; i++) 
            labels[DIGIT_COUNT - i - 1].setText(numbers[(number / (int) Math.pow(10, i)) % 10]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        final Display dis = new Display();
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.add(dis);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);

        new SwingWorker<Void, Integer>() {

            @Override
            protected Void doInBackground() {

                int x = 0;
                while (x <= MAX) {
                    dis.setNumber(x);
                    x++;
                    try {
                        Thread.sleep(1000);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
                return null;
            }
        }.execute();
    }
}
```

I believe this way of counting seconds is not good because the calls inside the worker thread await the return of calling `setNumber` on the event dispatch thread which takes some time and also `sleep` might not be too accurate, but it's just a simulation. If anyone can suggest the proper way of running a timer in the background (which updates some component) it would be nice.